# Angular $http is sending OPTIONS instead of PUT (not POST)

Tags: python, angularjs, http-headers, cors, put

[image]I have read all the issues about this angular's problem, but Angular $http is sending OPTIONS instead of PUT. (with POST everything is ok) Our project is in google app engine (python)

I have

```
$httpProvider.defaults.useXDomain = true;
delete $httpProvider.defaults.headers.common['X-Requested-With'];
```

in config and

```
$scope.updateUser = function () {
    /*$http.put(myurl, {
        admin: "on"
    }).success(function (result) {
        console.log(result);
        $scope.resultPost = result;
    }).error(function (result) {
        console.log(result);
    });*/
    var uri = my url;
    $http({
        method: 'PUT',
        url: uri,
        headers: {"Content-Type": "application/json;charset=UTF-8"},
        data: {}
    });
};
```

Any advice about a solution would be appreaciated.

Comment: Has absolutely nothing to do with angular. It is the browser that sends OPTIONS as part of CORS spec for cross domain requests. You need to enable CORS at server. Please look at error in browser console and google that error. Issue comes up here numerous times a day and there is lots of available documentation on CORS

Comment: CORS enabled at server. There isn't any problem about POST.

Comment: Then it isn't enabled properly. Copy the response  headers from a request from browser dev tools network and post in question

Comment: I have posted response headers

Comment: Clearly missing all the proper `access-control` headers needed for CORS. Make sure you are including OPTIONS in methods also.

Comment: no...CORS is enabled on server. There is nothing you can do in client to manage CORS

Comment: Looks like all the important tags were removed from this question. your issue is really how to properly set up CORS in the server environment

Comment: But you need to also change context of question. I suggest you create a new one related to CORS set up and environment since nothing is shown here with that regard

Comment: My problem is about angular, because another developer works in backend section and insistend that problem is in angular. And I couldnt continue on frontend because this issue

Comment: Well those headers you have shown clearly indicate otherwise. If they are testing with a REST client , it won't be subject to CORS restrictions the way a browser is

Answer (score 2):

Sending request with `OPTIONS` method is correct behaviour by the browser when using CORS.

Read more about CORS here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Access_control_CORS

This article explains why it needs to do it this way. More specificaly section titled "Preflighted requests":

> Unlike simple requests (discussed above), "preflighted" requests first send an HTTP request by the OPTIONS method to the resource on the other domain, in order to determine whether the actual request is safe to send

Comment: why did you remove python tag from question? If OP is using python on server surely that is relevant to situation

Comment: Question isn't asking anything about Python, whether OP's using GAE is irellevant, he's asking what's wrong with his Angular code. How to setup GAE for CORS isn't related to Angular and is a topic for another question.

Comment: But CORS is a server side problem. Agree question needs reworking but your answer doesn't clarify that

Comment: postman is not subject to CORS restrictions the way browsers are